# set collectionView height relative to screen height in tableView cell iOS in storyBoard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, constraints

can we set  a constraint for setting UICollectionView height to relative of the Device Screen from storyboard ??  i can set it to the tableViewCell's height but how to set for the Screen Height ??  all i wanna do is make a relative constraint between  Screen Height and the View(which is inside a TableViewCell) so that i can give it the hight of half of device screen

as you can see in the size inspector i can set it the constraint for my view to its superView which is TableViewCell

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your constraint is fine, you have to set the constraint as "Equal Height" between the two views, and the multiplier to 0.5 for the value to be halved. If the view 1 and view 2 aren't in the correct order (superview is half of collectionview), you must invert the "First" and "Second" views of the constraint.

From your screenshot I can see that all that looks fine, but you have a constraint conflict (red arrow). Read it and see what's wrong.

Usually that means you have a constraint that says "do X" and another that says "do Y" and are conflicting. If you know it's from your last constraint, remove it and think "why", you'll figure it out. If you don't know where it came from, chose between the given choices in the red arrow submenu. In your case, it could be the following :

> Your collectionview is set to have both 50% of height, and full height, because you might have set "Top-Bottom-Left-Right" AND "height". here, you could remove bottom or top.

Just imagine yourself as Xcode, if I tell you where to put your collectionview on Left, Right, Top and Height, you don't need to know where the bottom arrives, because the height is enough. IF you do need a constraint for the bottom, it has to be set to something else than Equal, or have a lower priority.

Sometimes it means your view doesn't have all required constraints, for example "No Y constraint defined for collectionview". Just make sure you have set everything right after you've set the height.

Again, only the information in the red arrow menu (conflicting constraints) can help us determine the issue easily. I'm not gonna lie I don't really wanna read all your constraints from the left menu manually.

But with this information you should have more than enough to resolve this yourself.

Comment: hey brah , maybe my question is not clear enough but i wanted to set the height of collectionView to be the half of ScreenHeight (which i ended up using an IBoutlet of my constraint and manually assigning the height to it ) great explanation though , appreciate your effort. thanks

Comment: Oh, the screen, not the superview. But couldnt you simply drag and drop from the collection to the top most UiView of your xib and set Equal Height? Doing it programatically is the same though, so whatever you do is fine. but be careful with doing it in code, because iPhone 6Plus and 6SPlus .Frame are not fully sized in viewdidload. You have to use the UIScreen (UIWindow) object

Comment: oh i'll take care of it , thanks :D ,  yeah i can not simply do it in my storyboard because the superView is Tableview which dont have any height

Comment: It's because TableViewControllers are for ladies. Real men do everything by hand and get to use the UIView on top. :p
Anyway, glad you got it all working, have a good day :)